# Why isn't the variable being re-populated when initState is called?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to populate the search with notes list, I fetch from the database.
The database call is made in the `initState`, so that notes are there for the searchDelegate to instantiate with.

### Problem

1. The `initState` isn't being called again when the search is closed. Which results in erroneous search results.
2. It shouldn't display the deleted entries, how to reactively remove that ( probably provider ).

Here's the video of the problem : [noteList not updating](https://youtu.be/3_69gRAvg6Y).

#### Tree Structure of the directory :

```sh
.
├── main.dart
├── models
│   └── note.dart
├── screens
│   ├── another_screen.dart
│   ├── note_detail.dart
│   ├── note_list.dart
│   ├── outer_page.dart
│   └── search_screen.dart
├── utils
│   ├── database_helper.dart
│   └── noteHelper.dart
└── widgets
    ├── noteCard.dart
    └── noteListCard.dart

4 directories, 11 files
```

The code for `outer_page.dart` :

```dart
~~~ SNIP imports ~~~~
class OuterPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return OuterPageState();
  }
}

class OuterPageState extends State<OuterPage> {
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  //Calling search delegate class
  SearchAppBarDelegate _searchDelegate;
  int _selectedTab = 0;
  final _pageOptions = [
    NoteList(),
    AnotherScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  void initState() {
    updateListView().then((results) {
      this._searchDelegate = SearchAppBarDelegate(results);
    });
    print("initState called");
    super.initState();
  }
~~~ SNIP other code ~~~~
```

Here's the [repo](https://github.com/LuD1161/notes_app/tree/reusable_components) ( the `reusable_components` branch ).

#### A few of my own ideas to solve this :

1. Pass the search delegate from `note_list`
2. Use Provider : Don't know how to use this with database, it would be great if someone could help me work this out. I suppose this would also be a cleaner way of doing this. I've tried provider a few times but am confused if is this a 'state' that I am managing or not :(

For the **2nd problem** i.e. search showing deleted entries :

**Possible solution :** From what I understand is, `provider` would delete the entry from its local copy notes and **also** call the database to delete the same, right ?

Please help me understand if there's any flaw in doing this or is it the proper way of doing it.

#### Looking for 'clean' way to solve this, not a hacky solution.

Thanks.

Let me know, if any more info is required.